# Exception When Running Oozie Workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a simple workflow I created in Hue that just calls a Spark job with no arguments, but am getting an exception when running it. This is running on a Google DataProc cluster and using Oozie 4.2.0 with Hue 3.9 for a UI and running it.

I have made sure that the mapreduce.framework.name is for yarn. I found a few solutions online so far, but all of those revolved around issues with the workflow XML. I have rebuilt by hand and it is doing the same thing that way as well.

Here is the code for my workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="Drug_File_Price_Generation" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="spark-22ca"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="spark-22ca">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>local[*]</master>
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>MySpark</name>
          <class>com.company.drug.GenerateDrugPriceFile</class>
        <jar>gs://customers/jar/DrugFileImport-assembly-1.0.jar</jar>
    </spark>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

Here is the output from the log I am receiving:

```
2016-03-22 19:27:27,927  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[sayle.matthews] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Drug_File_Price_Generation] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]

2016-03-22 19:27:27,930  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[sayle.matthews] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Drug_File_Price_Generation] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE

2016-03-22 19:27:27,930  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[sayle.matthews] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Drug_File_Price_Generation] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!

2016-03-22 19:27:27,963  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W

2016-03-22 19:27:27,963  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@:start:

2016-03-22 19:27:27,976  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[sayle.matthews] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Drug_File_Price_Generation] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@spark-22ca] Start action [0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@spark-22ca] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]

2016-03-22 19:27:32,670  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[cluster-1-m.c.server-name.internal] USER[sayle.matthews] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Drug_File_Price_Generation] JOB[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000011-160322181838855-oozie-oozi-W@spark-22ca] Error starting action [spark-22ca]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:456)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:436)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:454)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$3.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:437)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$3.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:435)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createJobClient(HadoopAccessorService.java:435)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createJobClient(JavaActionExecutor.java:1329)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1080)
    ... 10 more
```

Edit:
As requested here is my mapred-site.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.maps</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <description>
      The default number of map tasks per job. Ignored when mapred.job.tracker
      is &amp;amp;amp;quot;local&amp;amp;amp;quot;.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>3072</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>cluster-1-m:10020</value>
    <description>MapReduce JobHistory Server IPC host:port</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>cluster-1-m:19888</value>
    <description>MapReduce JobHistory Server Web UI host:port</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>6144</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4915m</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>
      Property from MapReduce version 1 still used for TeraGen sharding.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <description>
      The number of threads to use to list and fetch block locations for the
      specified input paths. Note: multiple threads should not be used if a
      custom non thread-safe path filter is used. Setting a larger value than
      the default of 1 can significantly improve job startup overhead,
      especially if using GCS as input with multi-level directories, such
      as in partitioned Hive tables.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4915m</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>6144</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
    <value>8</value>
    <description>
      The default number of reduce tasks per job. Typically set to 99%of the
      cluster's reduce capacity, so that if a node fails the reduces can still
      be executed in a single wave. Ignored when mapred.job.tracker is
      &amp;amp;amp;quot;local&amp;amp;amp;quot;.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2457m</value>
    <source>programatically</source>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.working.dir</name>
    <value>/user/${user.name}</value>
    <description>
      The FileSystem working directory to use for relative paths.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>
      Updated file output committer algorithm in Hadoop 2.7+. Significantly
      improves commitJob times when using the Google Cloud Storage connector.
      See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPEDUCE-4815 for more details.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
    <value>/hadoop/mapred/local</value>
    <description>
      Directories on the local machine in which to store mapreduce temp files.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.bq.project.id</name>
    <value>instant-bonbon-111304</value>
    <description>
      Google Cloud Project ID to use for BigQuery operations.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.bq.output.buffer.size</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
    <description>
      The size in bytes of the output buffer to use when writing to BigQuery.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.bq.gcs.bucket</name>
    <value>dataproc-efab4f81-9a3a-4e62-ae58-db967541284c-us</value>
    <description>
      The GCS bucket holding temporary BigQuery data for the input connector.
    </description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Edit 2:
Can't get Hue to export the job.properties file, but here is the one I generated when I tested this on the command-line. I am sure the generated one won't be too different.

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8050
master=local[*]
oozie.wf.application.path=/home/sayle_matthews/workflow
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

Comment: Adding `mapred-site.xml` to your question would be nice.

Comment: Added. It's the default, so not sure if it will help but never hurts.

Comment: And `job.properties`?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to export that out of Hue it appears. Attaching one I wrote manually when I did this on the command-line.

Comment: I can't really help more than ask for those files, because I don't know what machines and ports you are connecting to, but the error clearly states to check "correspond server addresses"

Comment: Thanks. Yeah unfortunately I can't get that file out of Hue. Everything is on the name node and pointing to itself by the server name. I am not sure if that's the problem but changing to localhost broke a lot of other things.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that you should use the full domain name of the nameNode and jobTracker instead localhost. Your properties file is passed around all the nodes in the cluster because that is how Oozie works. Not all nodes are running the nameNode **and** jobTracker on themselves.

Comment: That would be something I would hope Hue accounts for since it is the runner in this case.

Comment: So `mapred-site.xml` is the default. I'm assuming the `code-site` and `hdfs-site` are defaults also? Have you changed any configs?

Comment: I had to change hdfs-site to allow the proxying of hue to access hdfs. That was just enabling the webhdfs part.

Comment: Is this a file on HDFS `/home/sayle_matthews/workflow`? And is Oozie able to read `gs://customers/jar/DrugFileImport-assembly-1.0.jar` and does that file exist?

Comment: Yes that is the file that was used locally. It should be able to read as it works fine calling spark submit on command line using that file. That's how our current cron job works. Google has pieces under the hood that let let Spark and Hadoop understand the gs protocol.

Comment: "the file that was used locally" -- As I said before, Oozie isn't running on your local filesystem. You need all shared resources to be located on HDFS

Comment: Sorry when I say locally I mean running locally and not doing it all through Hue.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, still. If you entered `/some/path/` into Hue instead of `hdfs:///some/path`, then it might think you want to read local disk

Comment: Sorry to interfere with your chat, but... did you *ever* run a job with that Oozie setup, before trying the non-trivial Spark action? E.g. a simple "Hello, World" Shell action?

Comment: Side note: "job.properties" is just another "foo / bar" thing. On the command line you can give it any name you want, and with the Java or REST API it's not even a file. Anyway... you **can** display the actual parameters of any job that shows in the Hue dashboard, by clicking on the [Configuration] tab or sthg like that.

Comment: Oozie Spark action is pretty buggy http://gethue.com/use-the-spark-action-in-oozie/, and like Samsom asked, does the Hive2 example work? The generated job.properties will be written in the workspace by Hue BTW.

Comment: Sorry guys, this started to take too much time and appears that Oozie has issues on Google's Dataproc cluster so I was instructed to find another way by management. So I went ahead and wrote my own workflow using Pub/Sub and Node. So I am abandoning this and probably won't look at it again as my solution is working much better.

Comment: @Khirok for completeness, it is recommended you post your Pub/Sub solution to this issue as it will help the community members who are also affected by this.